# State value not updating reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
class RaisablePaper extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super();
            this.state = {
                state1: "state1",
                openNow: props.boxOpen,

            };
        }
}
```

I am trying to send value to this class by doing `<RaisablePaper boxOpen={this.state.dOpen}/>`. But whenever the dOpen gets changed it does not seem to update the `openNow`. Help would very much appreciated.

Comment: well dOpen is just the parent state variable which is being changed from the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the state before mounting the component in the `constructor`, which will not be fired again when the props change. For that you can use React's `componentWillReceiveProps`, which will be called when new props are sent to the component.

```js
class RaisablePaper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      state1: "state1",
      openNow: props.boxOpen
    };
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({
      openNow: props.boxOpen
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It is what i was looking for but unfortunately did not know the name. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad I could help. Check out [the documentation for React's lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), they can be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to use the props directly instead of worrying about syncing it to your state. It's a good idea in general to rely on props as much as possible, and only involve state when absolutely necessary.

But Fabian Schultz is absolutely right -- your constructor only runs once, before the component is mounted, so you'll never receive the subsequent updates if the component is relying on state which is initialized during construction.

---

I'm just imagining how you're using the `boxOpen` state to show an example; you can follow the same general idea with whatever your `render` method is doing.

```js
class RaisablePaper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.boxOpen ? 'is-open' : ''}>
        Here's some content...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```